# What is the highest gimbal range ever used on an engine?

Tags: engine-design, engines, gimbaled-engines

This [answer here mentions the STS-94's ability to gimbal up to 20 degrees](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/14316/25224) in all directions, that got me thinking, what exactly is the maximum ever feasibly implemented? I've seen a lot of information on different forums mentioning numbers below 20 degrees. I was hoping for something like this comparison of all engines:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_rocket_engines

But with the gimbal range for all engines also included, or at the very minimum a guess at the highest gimbal range ever used in a production rocket.

Comment: Of possible interest: non-gimbaling TVC: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25442/what-was-the-purpose-of-the-small-red-tank-attached-to-the-titan-centaur-launche/25448#25448

Comment: @OrganicMarble was that a solid booster though? If so that's neat, I didn't know of any gimballed (for lack of a better term) solid boosters, especially not the TVC style of attitude control! Can that be used to exceed the range that traditional gimballing can accomplish?

Comment: 20 degrees is certainly the highest range of gimbaling I know of, but it’s not a figure that’s frequently provided alongside other engine specs.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn yes it was a solid, but no I don't think the range was all that large. And I agree that AFAIK shuttle had the highest gimbal range.

Comment: @RussellBorogove so basically the one I listed was the highest? I thought 20 degrees sounded very high in comparison to the average 6 degrees or 11 degrees I found quoted on most craft.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I'll go ahead and close it if you want, or you can post an answer and get points if you like. Up to you.

Comment: Incidentally, STS-94 (or STS-xx in general) is a *mission* identifier, referring to a single flight, not the name of the launcher. The design of the complete stack is “STS” or informally “space shuttle”; the spaceplane without boosters and external tank is “STS orbiter” or “space shuttle orbiter”. The individual orbiter airframes can be identified by name or as OV-10x numbers.

Comment: I can’t rule out that larger gimbal ranges have been used on something like guided missiles (though those generally use fins for maneuvering), and while my knowledge of launchers is broad, it’s not encyclopedic, so I am reluctant to answer.

Comment: @RussellBorogove awesome :). Thanks for the diction lesson-- I'm very unfamiliar with how things are labelled in the SpaceExploration world. Thank you for also correcting me on that, really helpful. I'm guessing this was the columbia then, STS-94 was the 94th flight in the shuttle missions? Great to know, I'll be more careful to label the question with the craft instead of the mission label next time I ask.

Comment: The numbering is complicated: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Shuttle_missions

Comment: As it happens, STS-94 was the 84th flight of the program, and the 23rd flight of OV-102, Columbia.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an exhaustive list, feel free to add to it.

---

#### RS-25  - (SLS, Shuttle)

[±12.5°](https://www.nasa.gov/missions/highlights/webcasts/shuttle/sts111/ssme-qa.html)

#### Merlin - Falcon 9

[5-10°](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23654)?

#### Shuttle SRBs

[8°](https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/srb.html)

#### RS-68 - SLS, Delta IV

[6°](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20090014109.pdf)

#### F1 - Saturn V

[5.15°](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=32445.0;attach=535877)

#### HM7-B - Ariane 5 upper stage

[3°](http://www.spaceflight101.net/ariane-5-eca.html)

#### NERVA - concept

[3°](https://fas.org/nuke/space/nerva-spec.pdf)

#### Long March

[yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_March_7)

#### Soyuz

[0°](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=22540.0) (although the [RD-00110R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-0110R) Vernier thrusters have 45°)

Comment: "yes" haha, I take that to mean they can't do it very well? "Two are fixed and two can gimbal in two axis."

Comment: Is "TS-25" a typo for RS-25, aka SSME?

Comment: I think vernier thrusters would be an applicable, valid sub-class of the engines.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You are correct. Answer has been amended.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yes, the engines gimbal, but I couldn't get an exact number of degrees. If you can read Chinese, you can probably get an answer. Or maybe that's a "state secret".

Comment: Energia core engines gimbal up to 7° according to me in a comment without citation on another QA - finding a reference is left as an exercise. 